# How to create counters that display and increment dates in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, counters, context-mkiv, datetime

I need to create a document that has section titles named "October 1, 2012", "October 2, 2012", etc., like this:

```
\section{October 1, 2012}
    This is text for the first day.
\section{October 2, 2012}
    This is text for the second day.
```

Is there a simple way to create a counter, set to the initial date, and then to increment it? E.g.:

```
 \section{\insertdate\incrementdate}
     This is text for the first day.
 \section{\insertdate\incrementdate}
     This is text for the second day.
```

- This would need to know about leap years.
- When displayed in the table of contents, this should match the sections.

In some situations, I may need to query the current value of `year`, `month`, and `day`, e.g.:

```
This is month \month and year \year.
```

This would display:

```
This is month 10 and year 2012.
```

In other situations, I may need to use the current value of `year`, `month`, and `day`, in a conditional, e.g.:

```
IF day IS 1, THEN:
    "This is the start of a new month."
ELSE:
    "It is not the start of a new month."
```

How can such a counter be created in ConTeXt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation. The command `\setupdate` sets the current date (its syntax is same as `\date` command); the command `\incrementdate` increments the date; and the command `\getdate` typesets the current date.

You can access the current day, month, and year using `\getdate[...]`, which accepts the same specification as `\date`. So `\getdate[month]` gives the name of the month (in the current language), `\getdate[m]` gives the number of the current month, `\getdate[weekday]` gives the day of the week, etc.

```
\unprotect

\newcount\daycounter
\newcount\monthcounter
\newcount\yearcounter

\unexpanded\def\setupdate
  {\dosingleargument\setup_date_aux}

\def\setup_date_aux[#1]%
  {\letdummyparameter\c!d\normalday
   \letdummyparameter\c!m\normalmonth
   \letdummyparameter\c!y\normalyear
   \getdummyparameters[#1]%
   \daycounter  \directdummyparameter\c!d\relax
   \monthcounter\directdummyparameter\c!m\relax
   \yearcounter \directdummyparameter\c!y\relax
  }

\unexpanded\def\incrementdate
  {\getdayspermonth\yearcounter\monthcounter
   \doifelse\numberofdays{\the\daycounter}
      {\daycounter\plusone
       \doifelse\!!twelve{\the\monthcounter}
          {\monthcounter\plusone
           \advance\yearcounter\plusone}
          {\advance\monthcounter\plusone}}
      {\advance\daycounter\plusone}}

\def\getdate
    {\date[d=\the\daycounter, m=\the\monthcounter, y=\the\yearcounter]}

\protect

\setupdate[d={25},m={12},y={2011}]

\starttext
\placecontent
\dorecurse{200}
{\expanded{\section{\getdate}}
 The current month is \getdate[month] \getdate[weekday]
 \incrementdate}
\stoptext
```

As can be seen from the output of the above example, this implementation correctly handles leap years and works in section titles (provided you use `\expanded`).